# REST service on default port 8080

Tags: rest, web-services, apache-camel, restlet, spring-camel

Sorry if the question is already asked.
I am trying a REST DSL with XML and I have the following code :

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <restConfiguration component="restlet"/>

  <rest path="/say">
    <get uri="/hello">
      <to uri="direct:hello"/>
    </get>
  </rest>

  <route>
    <from uri="direct:hello"/>
    <transform>
      <constant>Hello World</constant>
    </transform>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

This code runs on any other port if I manually set the port except on the default port 8080. How do I make it run on the default port? **I would like this to work on http://localhost:8080/say/hello**

I have tried the following for setting up ports manually:

```
<restConfiguration component="restlet" port="8080"/>
```

Logs when 8080 is tried :

```
<body>
    <h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - JBWEB000263: Servlet.init() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception</h1>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000066: Exception report</p>
    <p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u>JBWEB000263: Servlet.init() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception</u></p>
    <p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
            fulfilling this request.</u></p>
    <p><b>JBWEB000070: exception</b>
        <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: JBWEB000263: Servlet.init() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:656)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>
    </p>
    <p><b>JBWEB000071: root cause</b>
        <pre>org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cxf' is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1111)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1127)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:80)
    org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:77)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:656)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</pre>
```

Comment: Any chance 8080 is busy with something else?

Comment: Are you running Camel as a standalone or in a Spring Boot application?

Comment: @AntonGoncharov I am running it as a standalone.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when it attempts to start on 8080? Could you share the logs please?

Comment: @AntonGoncharov I am getting a 404 not found exception.

Comment: @AntonGoncharovwhen I tried it on postman I got the logs attached.

Comment: Dude! That's a JBoss server responding to you on port 8080. Shut it down first, and start Camel standalone application. You'd be OK.